# Any way to improve time spent in `Kernel#require`?

Tags: ruby, swing, jruby, mechanize

I'm developing a simple desktop gui (swing) app in JRuby 9.0.0.0-pre2 (latest rvm version), and it is a step up from 1.7.19. It uses mechanize to access a corporate website and upload a file. The app has a JFrame with 2 images (a few kb), a JButton, and a bit textis, and it takes about 8 seconds to load the window. These loading times are unacceptable.

The builtin profiler `jruby --profile script.rb` shows this:

```
  total        self    children       calls  method
  5.36        0.03        5.32         806  Kernel.require
  4.54        0.00        4.53         371  Kernel.require
  4.53        0.00        4.53           8  Kernel.require_relative
  1.28        0.08        1.20        2691  Array#each
  1.20        0.10        1.11          35  Kernel.load
```

Besides `Array#each`, all methods are `Kernel` methods.  Is this what Aaron Patterson was talking about in Railsconf2015? Or is this a specific to JRuby implementation? Can I boost this? Client didn't help, and I'm not sure if I can turn this on when I warble it to a jar even if it did help.

Comment: This sounds like normal jRuby to me - there is a hit on load time as the JVM starts.

Comment: Is mechanize relevant at all to your question?

Comment: @sawa maybe it adds to the overhead as being required along with it's dependencies (nokogiri etc), that's the only reason i added this.

Comment: Try running VisualVM profiling as well, to get the Java's part.

Comment: [JRuby: Improving Startup Time](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Improving-startup-time) article on official Wiki might be of help.

Comment: It's not a Java issue.  It's a require issue.  I changed positions of every require to be when called and not in the beginning of file and startup time, so that when it runs, it has the least possible work to do.  And as they already state in the JRuby wiki, it has surprisingly good results.  I have lowered the total run time to about 5 seconds by moving require around.

Comment: I wouldn't say a Java issue, but definitely a JVM issue.  `require` involves loading of `.jar` files, in a good scenario, or loading and compiling of `.rb` files, in a not-so-good scenario. The less of that you need to do, the faster you go, as you found out for yourself.

Comment: So how can i profile this?  How can i improve it more? I'm sorry if this is a bit nubish topic, i'm fairly new to JRuby and i'm trying to find out more and more as i go

PS: with warble, can i precompile the .rb files to class files so they will load faster?